# Connection between nginx and tomcat gets hung after some time

Tags: apache, tomcat, nginx

We have a REST API based module deployed on AWS. We have set up a load balancer as the first point of contact which inturn contacts with nginx server which depending on request directs it to either apache or tomcat.
But after some time the communication between nginx and tomcat gets hung up with the following info message on nginx log

```
2015/07/09 07:07:43 [info] 29889#0: *40458 epoll_wait() reported that client prematurely closed connection, so upstream connection is closed too while connecting to upstream
```

After this any REST API call to tomcat fails with 504 on browser, but the communication between nginx and apache works perfectly fine.

We have made all the following changes suggested on various stackoverflow forums such as:-

```
proxy_connect_timeout  600s;
proxy_send_timeout  600s;
proxy_read_timeout  600s;
fastcgi_send_timeout 600s;
fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
```

or

```
fastcgi_ignore_client_abort on;
```

Can you guys please suggest what could be wrong on our side?